# AWS Private R53 hosted zone A record not resolving within same VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-route53

I am having trouble having an A record on an AWS R53 private hosted zone resolve to a private IP within the same VPC. Our VPC has DNS hostnames and DNS resolution enabled. I've tried using a CNAME record pointing to the private IP, but am unable to get it to resolve (via ping from the Windows server).

I've verified the hosted zone is associated with the same VPC that EC2 instance resides in. Can this be done without a VPC resolver endpoint?

Comment: First of all an IP address you would want to use an `A` rcord, not a `CNAME`. See: https://serverfault.com/questions/377934/can-i-use-cname-with-ip-address-why-if-works-sometimes. Now I don't really understand, did you try it with an `A`, it did not work and went on to try it with a `CNAME`. ?

Comment: You don't need a VPC endpoint resolver. You just need to associate the Route53 private hosted zone with the VPC. And as mentioned above, you need to be sure to use an `A` record for an IP address, not a `CNAME` record.

Comment: The R53 hosted zone is definitely associated with the same VPC (I only tried the CNAME as a test, it's set as an A record). I'm stumped at what else is holding this up.

Comment: I'm not sure if this makes a difference, but the DHCP option set on the VPC is set to use our Directory Services DNS servers instead of the AWS Default DNS (this instance is domain joined).

Comment: From [Considerations when working with a private hosted zone - Amazon Route 53](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/hosted-zone-private-considerations.html): _"If you have configured custom DNS servers on Amazon EC2 instances in your VPC, you must configure those DNS servers to route your private DNS queries to the IP address of the Amazon-provided DNS servers for your VPC. If you want to route DNS queries between VPCs and your network, you can use Resolver."_